# How to get the selected option in a <datalist>

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Hello I have the following datalist:

```html
<input id='titleDataLstTxt' list='titleDataLst' type='text'>
<datalist id='titleDataLst' >
  <template repeat='{{title in titles}}'>
    <option value='{{title}}'>{{title}}</option>
  </template>
</datalist>
```

where List titles =  [ '', 'a, 'b', 'c' ];

How can I get the selected option in the datalist.

Thanks

Comment: Solved - Bind the text input as per usual. <input id='titleDataLstTxt' list='titleDataLst' type='text' value="{{firstName}}"> where     @CustomTag( 'name-component' )
class NameElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin 
{ observable String firstName = ''; }

Comment: You could answer your own question and accept it.